# How to create the edit form in Silverstripe 4.2 frontend?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I wish to create the edit form in Silverstripe 4.2, much like this Stack Overflow's edit function that i'm looking for.

**EDITED:** I want to be able to have a page that is only available to the registered member of my website that they can post their class listings on the Frontend (not in CMS) as an owner, and need to have a 'edit' click that takes you to an identical form (same ClassListingForm) that lets member owner to edit/update their own class listings that they have posted. I have everything working except the edit and submit functions which I'm stuck on at the moment.

I have a link for editing the specific class listing:

```
<a href="{$Top.Link}edit/{$ID}">Edit class listing</a></div>
```

It does redirected to 404 page not found with this url shown:

"http://.../learners/class-listings/edit/61"

Here's the code below I have so far, the ClassListingForm is working fine, just need to get the **EditListingForm** and **doClassListing** functions to work properly, and i may be doing something wrong in these codes? or is there a better way of doing the edit form properly which i'm unable to find anywhere on the search for specific on what i need as there's not much tutorial that covers the EditForm function on the SilverStripe lessons.

```
<?php

class ClassListings extends DataObject {

    private static $table_name = 'ClassListings';

    private static $db = [
        'CourseTitle' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'CourseLocation' => 'Varchar(255)',
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'ClassListingPage' => ClassListingPage::class,
    ];
}
```

```
<?php

class ClassListingPageController extends PageController {

        private static $allowed_actions = [
            'ClassListingForm',
            'ClassEditForm'
        ];

        public function ClassListingForm() {

            $id = (int)$this->urlParams['ID'];
            $data = ($id)? $data = ClassListings::get()->byID($id) : false;

            $form = Form::create(
              $this,
              __FUNCTION__,
              FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('CourseTitle', 'Course title:')
                    ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'NZSL Level 1, NZSL 1A')
                    ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the course title field')
                    ->addExtraClass('requiredField CourseTitle'),
                TextField::create('CourseLocation','Region:')
                    ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter region')
                    ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the region field')
                    ->addExtraClass('requiredField'),
                HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID')->setValue($ClassListingPageID)
              ),
              FieldList::create(
                  FormAction::create('handleClassListing')
                      ->setTitle('Post your class listing')
                      ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary primary')
              ),
              RequiredFields::create(
                'CourseTitle',
                'CourseLocation'
              )
          );

          $form->loadDataFrom(Member::get()->byID(Member::currentUserID()));
          $form->getSecurityToken()->getValue();

                    if ($form->hasExtension('FormSpamProtectionExtension')) {
                $form->enableSpamProtection();
            }

                    $data = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
                    return $data ? $form->loadDataFrom($data) : $form;
          }

          public function handleClassListing($data, $form) {

                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
                $session->set("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data", $data);
                $class = ClassListings::create($this->owner);

                $class->CourseTitle = $data['CourseTitle'];
                $class->CourseLocation = $data['CourseLocation'];
                $class->ID = $data['ID'];

                $class->ClassListingPageID = $this->ID;
                $form->saveInto($class);
                $class->write();

                $session->clear("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
                $form->sessionMessage('Your class listing has been posted!','good');
                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

                return $this->redirect($this->Link());
            }

            public function ClassEditForm() {

                $ClassListingPageID = (int)$this->urlParams['ID'];
                $data = ($ClassListingPageID)? $data = ClassListings::get()->byID($ClassListingPageID) : false;
                $var = $this->getRequest()->getVar('$data');

                    if($var){
                        $form = Form::create(
                                    $this,
                                __FUNCTION__,
                                FieldList::create(
                                        TextField::create('CourseTitle', 'Course title:')
                                            ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'NZSL Level 1, NZSL 1A')
                                            ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the course title field')
                                            ->addExtraClass('requiredField CourseTitle'),
                                        TextField::create('CourseLocation','Region:')
                                            ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter region')
                                            ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the region field')
                                            ->addExtraClass('requiredField'),
                                        HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID')->setValue($ClassListingPageID)
                                ),
                                FieldList::create(
                                        FormAction::create('doClassListing')
                                                ->setTitle('Post your class listing')
                                                ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary primary')
                                ),
                                RequiredFields::create(
                                        'CourseTitle',
                                        'CourseLocation',
                                )
                        );

                        $form->loadDataFrom(ClassListings::get()->filter(['ClassListingPageID' => $var])[0]);
                        $form->getSecurityToken()->getValue();

                        if ($form->hasExtension('FormSpamProtectionExtension')) {
                                $form->enableSpamProtection();
                        }

                        $data = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
                        return $data ? $form->loadDataFrom($data) : $form;
                    }
                    return;
            }

      public function doUpdateClassListing($data, Form $form) {

                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
                $session->set("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data", $data);
                $class = ClassListings::create($this->owner);

                $class->CourseTitle = $data['CourseTitle'];
                $class->CourseLocation = $data['CourseLocation'];
                $class->ID = $data['ID'];

                $class->ClassListingPageID = $this->ID;
                $form->saveInto($class);
                $class->write();

                $session->clear("FormData.{$form->getName()}.data");
                $form->sessionMessage('Your class listing has been updated!','good');
                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

            return $this->redirect($this->Link());

      }
}
```

Comment: Do let me know if the title/topic is not correct for this post, then let me know what's the proper title for this. :D

Comment: What does not work about the 'edit' and 'submit' parts of your work? It may help to be more specific about this, so that readers can understand the nature of your problem.

Comment: @halfer i've updated/edited above on this post with extra specific. hope that is enough. Do let me know if need more.

Comment: OK. What should the URL be instead of the one that is rendered?

Comment: The url is correct for http://.../learners/class-listings/edit/61 as i mentioned in the post, but the issue is i'm getting 404 error page which i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i post this answer to share in case if others have the same issue i had.

Finally got it working and solved the issue now, have replaced whole the codes for both **ClassEditForm** and **doUpdateClassListing** methods, and also created another funcation called **Edit**:

```
public function Edit(HTTPRequest $request) {
    $id = (int)$request->param('ID');
    $class = ClassListings::get()->byID($id);
    if (!$class || !$class->exists()) {
         return ErrorPage::response_for(404);
    }
    $form = $this->ClassEditForm($class);
    $return = $this->customise(array(
         'Title' => 'Edit: ' . $class->CourseTitle,
         'Form' => $form,
    ));

    return $return = $return->renderWith(array('ClassListingPage_edit', 'Page'));
}

public function ClassEditForm() {

        $id = (int)$this->urlParams['ID'];
        $class = ClassListings::get()->byID($id);

        $fields = new FieldList(
            HiddenField::create('ID')->setValue($id),
            TextField::create('CourseTitle', 'Course title:')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'NZSL Level 1, NZSL 1A')
                ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the course title field')
                ->addExtraClass('requiredField CourseTitle'),
            TextField::create('CourseLocation','Region:')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter region')
                ->setCustomValidationMessage('Please enter the region field')
                ->addExtraClass('requiredField')
          );
          $actions = new FieldList(
              FormAction::create('doUpdateClassListing')
                ->setTitle('Update your class listing')
                ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary primary')
          );
          $validator = new RequiredFields([
              'CourseTitle',
              'CourseLocation'
          ]);

        $form = Form::create($this, 'ClassEditForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);

        if ($class) $form->loadDataFrom($class);

        return $form;
}

public function doUpdateClassListing($data, Form $form) {

           if($data['ID']){
               $id = $data['ID'];
               $class = ClassListings::get()->byID($id);
           } else {
               $class = ClassListings::create();
           }

           $form->saveInto($class);
           $id = $class->write();
           $form->sessionMessage('Your class listing has been updated!','good');

           $this->redirect($this->Link() . "edit/".$id);
       }
```